# Disposing a Timer which apply changes to UI thread on closing WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

Consider a timer which would be fired on a Clicked event in a WPF application like so,

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(DoingWorkOnUI,null,0,5000);

    //Also doing long execution time job here. in another thread
}
```

Basically the problem is that if the user close the application, my timer is still running and never diposed resulting in an *task was cancelled* error. I'd like to dispose it in his callback but I can't figure out how I would do that.

Here is my try to it, I may be completely wrong, but I can catch the cancellation well, I just can't find a solution on how to dispose the timer.

```
private void DoingWorkOnUI(object state) {
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cts.Token;
    try
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            \\Doing work on UI
        }));
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        //Dispose Timer here ???
    }
    finally {
        //Disposing token
        cts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are instantiating the timer in Button_Click it looks like it should be Button_Click's reponsibility to clean-up. Taking this into account, I'd create a Timer instance for the whole class, which implements IDisposable. It then would be this class responsibility to dispose inside its dispose methods.

Comment: @SimonKatanski thank you for your comment, at the moment,  Button_Click's is indeed taking care of disposing the timer after the async job is done. But what if the user click the button and then close the application while the long execution time job is running. Then the timer would not be disposed. This is the problem I have.

Comment: Hence my comment on how you could make the Timer a global field for the class and Dispose it when the class is disposed (the one in which the button click happens)

Comment: Yes, I'm looking exactly into that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the `Closing` event of the window to dispose the timer.

Since you are creating an `IDisposable` field in your class, you should also implement the [dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern) in order to cope with best practice guidelines:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IDisposable
{
    private Timer _t;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Closing += OnClosing;
    }

    private void OnClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(_t != null)
            _t.Dispose();

        _t = new Timer(DoingWork, null, 0, 5000);
    }

    private void DoingWork(object state)
    {
        //....
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _t != null)
            _t.Dispose();
    }
}
```